# summing roots of unity elementary question (complex numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have $$e^{i2\pi/n} = w_n$$

the question asks to prove $S_n = w^0_n + w^1_n + \cdots + w^{n-1}_n = 1 + w^1_n + \cdots +w^{n-1}_n = 0$

The solutions are as follows:

$w_nS_n = w_n + w_n^2 + \cdots + 1$ so $(1-w_n)S_n = 0$ and as $w_n \not = 0$ $S_n = 0$. My question is why is $w_n \not= 0$, similarly if we use the geoemtric series we get $\dfrac{1-w^n_n}{1-w_n}$, why is $w_n \not= 1$?

Comment: You want to say $w_n\ne1$?

Comment: Why is there $w$ and $w_n$? Are they different or the same?

Comment: ill edit the question sorry

Comment: $n>1$ is required for $w_n\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

it's different from $0$ because $0$ is not a root of unity, but anyway in both aspects you use the fact that $w \not= 1$ which comes directly from the definition of $w = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$. a number $\exp(i 2\pi y)$ is equal to $1$ if and only if $y$ is a real integer - it's easy to see from the trigonometric definition of such a number (the one with sin and cos)

Comment: but $ y = n = 1$ gives $ w = 1$?

Comment: yeah, but for $n=1$ it is trivial (and not true) since the only root of unity of order $1$ is the unity, $1$, itself